# RequireJS issues while loading and Hamljs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, sammy.js

I am using requirejs + jquery + sammy.js + hamljs.
The template engine haml is not working : it runs sammy.haml, but `Haml` is defined for main.js but not for sammy.haml and cannot run in it. After the page is completely loaded, Haml exists for the console. Why Sammy does not get on well with HAML whereas it should be ?

```
requirejs.config({
     baseUrl: '../../components/',
     paths: {
         dropkick: 'jquery-dropkick2/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0',
         Ladda: 'Ladda/dist/ladda.min',
         'jquery-autosize': 'jquery-autosize/jquery.autosize',
         mixitup: 'mixitup/jquery.mixitup.min',
         jquery: 'jquery/jquery',
         sammy: 'sammy/lib/sammy',
         'sammy.haml': 'sammy/lib/plugins/sammy.haml',
         haml: 'haml/lib/haml',
         browser: 'jquery.browser/jquery.browser.min'
     },
     shim: {
         dropkick: {
             deps: ['jquery']
         },
         browser: {
             deps: ['jquery']
         },
         'sammy.haml': {
             deps: ['haml']
         }
     }

 });
 requirejs(['jquery', 'haml'], function($, Haml) { // They are to be loaded first
     requirejs(['sammy', 'sammy.haml', 'browser', 'markdown'], function(sammy, shaml, markdow) { // Then the others
            console.log(Haml); // WORK

            var app = sammy('#main', function() {
            var self = this;
            self.use(sammy.Haml);
            self.get('/upload', function(context) {
            context.app.swap('');
            var s = context.render('app/templates/upload.haml', {});
            s.appendTo(context.$element())




            });
        });


         });
         app.run();

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution ! I defined `window.Haml = haml` in the main file, and modified `sammy.haml.js` to get `window.Haml` function instead of `Haml` function.